# How to stop media recorder when it come two seconds in android

Tags: android

How do I stop the media recorder when it comes two minutes in android? I used stMaxduration and info listener, there is no guarantee in the call in the api.

Can anybody tell me any other way to achieve this? Provide code please

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way is to implement a countdown timer where you need to execute something after definite times. Below is the code. Here 120000 milliseconds  represents two minutes and 1000 milliseconds represents 1 second "`MyCount(120000, 1000)`"

```
MyCount counter = new MyCount(120000, 1000);

     public class MyCount extends CountDownTimer{
            public MyCount(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
            super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                //do your stuff here
            }

            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {



              }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Run using the threads when you stop the thread the media player will gets stop.
snippet:

```
Runnable r = new Runnable() 
{
  public void run() 
  {
    mp1.start();
  }
};
new Thread(r).start();
```